# Raven DB Replication Stats

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-http

I need to build a Health monitoring component for Raven DB Replication and Periodic Export

For Replication:
Last Run and Duration

For Periodic Export
Last Run, Duration, Size  of Export

Is there a client API much like getting Database Statistics and Server Statistics.

Raven 3.5

Answer (score 0):

For replication, you are looking for `/databases/[database_name]/replication/info` endpoint.

For periodic export, I'm not aware of any endpoint providing this information, perhaps someone else will supplement this if available.